# Is $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x-h\right)}{2h}=f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, derivatives

I was working on problem trying to find if some point on the function for some shape was a vertex of not by testing if $\lim_{h\to 0}f'(x+h)\not=f'(x)$ to see if the was a sudden change at the point as seen in vertices, but I kept running into the problem that the derivatives at those points where undefined or nonsensical either due to the function being piecewise or the derivative being $\frac{0}{0}$.

So I considered taking instead the derivative between the two points adjacent to $x$ as represent in the function in the title above of $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x-h\right)}{2h}$. But the question that I have is a valid redefinition?

Some of my thoughts:

If

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x-h\right)}{2h}=f'(x)$$

then $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x-h\right)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x+h\right)-f\left(x\right)}{h}$$

further implying that

$$f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)}{2}$$

When I input this function in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20h-%3E%200%20f(x)%3D(f(x%2Bh)%2Bf(x-h))%2F2) I get an output telling me that this is true for all analytical functions and the series expansion approaches $f(x)$. If I [remove the limit on $h$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%3D(f(x%2Bh)%2Bf(x-h))%2F2) WolframAlpha tells me that $f(x)$ must be even function, although I am skeptical of this.

Comment: The left side has an $h$ while the right side doesn't.  Perhaps you are missing some key `\lim_{h\to0}`?

Comment: It's not in general true, no. $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}=f'(x)$ is true, however.

Comment: For any continuous function $f(x)$, we have:
$$\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)=\lim_{h\to0}f(x-h)=f(x)$$

Comment: Note the converse is not true.  For example,
$$f(x)=1/x^2\\~\\\implies\frac10\ne\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}2=0$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's a bad example, since that $f$ is not defined at$x=0$, and presumably the unspoken assumption is that $f'(x)$ is defined, and hence $f(x)$ must be defined. There are better examples.

Comment: I believe you are working with the [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative), which equals the normal derivative when both exist.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am assuming that I always taking the limit of h as it approaches 0.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews As you wish, there are better examples.  Take $f(x)=|x|$.  We find that $f'(0)$ doesn't exist, but $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(-h)}{2h}=0$$(oh hey, these are the examples from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative#Examples) lol)

Comment: I guess _I am_ talking about symmetric derivatives, thanks.

Comment: In the same manner, $f(x)$ needn't be equal to $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}2$.  It does hold true, however, if $f(x)$ is continuous i.e. $f(x)=\lim_{h\to x}f(h)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We assume that $f$ is differentiable at $x$. By definition of differentiability at $x$,

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Moreover,

$$f'(x)= \lim_{-h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}= \lim_{-h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}.$$

These equalities are true in general by the definition of differentiability which states that the limit exists and does not depend on how you approach $x$. In particular, $$f'(x)=\dfrac{f'(x)+f'(x)}{2}= \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}.$$

Comment: It is important to note the converse is not true (you can see my comments on the main post)

Comment: Yes indeed! If you are not assuming derivability of $f$, then the symmetric derivative does not implies that your function is differentiable at a point. Your example with $f(x)= \vert  x \vert$ shows that

Answer (score 2):

For computational purposes,
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
$
is a more accurate approximation
to $f'(x)$ than
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$.

To see this,
since 
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+O(h^3)
$,
$\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
=f'(x)+hf''(x)/2+O(h^2)
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
&=\dfrac{(f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+O(h^3))-(f(x)-hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2+O(h^3))}{2h}\\
&=\dfrac{2hf'(x)+O(h^3)}{2h}\\
&=f'(x)+O(h^2)
\end{array}
$

and this is better
by a factor of $h$.